# Como posicionar JTabbedPane na metade inferior da tela?

Tags: java, swing, layout

Eu gostaria de fazer com que minha tela seja divida em no minimo duas partes, na parte de cima adicionarei alguns campos, e na parte de baixo, um `JTabbedPane` com algumas abas. O problema é que não sei como fazer isso, só consigo fazer o JTabbedPane ocupando toda a tela.

Segue uma imagem para ilustrar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tela:**

```
package tabbedpane;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Tela extends JFrame {

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    public Tela() {
        setTitle("Apenas um EXEMPLO");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Página 1", painel1());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Página 2", painel2());
        add(tabbedPane);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(600, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight()));
         setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tela tela  = new Tela();
    }

    public JComponent painel1() {
        JPanel painel1 = new JPanel();       
        JLabel label1;     
        label1 = new JLabel("Página 1");
        painel1.add(label1);
        return painel1; // retorna painel.
    }

    public JComponent painel2() {
        JPanel painel2 = new JPanel();       
        JLabel label2;
        label2 = new JLabel("Página 2");
        painel2.add(label2);
        return painel2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível fazendo apenas duas alterações:

- `add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);` - aproveitei do [**LayoutManager**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) padrão do `JFrame`, e indiquei a ele que posicione o componente na direção sul dentro do Frame.
- `tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), 300));` - Também defini um tamanho preferido para que o [**LayoutManager**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) saiba qual dimensão do componente.

Com as alterações, fica desta forma:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Tela extends JFrame {

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    public Tela() {
        setTitle("Apenas um EXEMPLO");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Página 1", painel1());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Página 2", painel2());
        tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), 300));

        /* -- exemplificacao de como adicionar o painel superior -- */
        JPanel painelSuperior = new JPanel();
        painelSuperior.add(new JButton("teste"));
        add(painelSuperior, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(600, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight()));
         setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tela tela  = new Tela();
    }

    public JComponent painel1() {
        JPanel painel1 = new JPanel();       
        JLabel label1;     
        label1 = new JLabel("Página 1");
        painel1.add(label1);
        return painel1; // retorna painel.
    }

    public JComponent painel2() {
        JPanel painel2 = new JPanel();       
        JLabel label2;
        label2 = new JLabel("Página 2");
        painel2.add(label2);
        return painel2;
    }
}
```

Resultado ao executar este código, já com um painel superior de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado !

Comment: @JoaoPedro disponha :)

Comment: @GustavoSantos não tem segredo, basta seguir o raciocinio das mudanças que eu destaquei, execute [**este código**](http://pastebin.com/TxKr9cLK) e veja o mesmo raciocinio aplicado a sua duvida(tem comentarios adicionais no código).

Comment: @GustavoSantos o ideal é sempre distribuir componentes atraves de containers, facilita reposicionar alguma coisa, como no seu caso. Não tem como sugerir nada sem ver e simular o problema, talvez seja o caso de criar uma pergunta mesmo com um exemplo que seja reproduzivel.